# Bootstrap datepicker without full bootstrap.css

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want to use the bootstrap-datetimepicker (https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

It works fine when everything is included, altough the icons doesn't show: http://prntscr.com/8bci9j

But besides that, I'm not using bootstrap for the site, and including the full bootstrap.css messes up with my styling. So I would just like the actually needed CSS-parts from the bootstrap.css - can anybody help me to get these? If I don't include bootstrap.css the datepicker is messed up, even though bootstrap-datepicker.css is included.

Comment: Inspect the element and select only the css class you want

Comment: Do inspect element and extract css class as datepicker is required and download the images icons and upload it to into your site.

Comment: `icons` might be stored in separate `img` folder which you might have not included and the path you need to take care after the folder has been placed.. check the css and check whether icons are there in that path?

Comment: I thought it would be too difficult considering that bootstrap effects everything - but it was actually quite easy! Thanks. The icons were glyphicons and needed a font.

Answer (score 1):

Its not that easy, there are number of css classes applied to elements from `bootstrap.css` depending the events like `hover` or `click`, etc.,

so its tough to get it work like that from any vendor css library. My suggestion is to update your local css so that it refers to specific elements everywhere in your script.

- Also refer to below MDN precendence table to know more about css priorities/precendences. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)
- if required use `!important`(in worst case) for the css classes which requires more priority.

---

### Reference from MDN about precendence:

**Selector Types**

The following list of selector types is by increasing specificity:

1. Universal selectors (i.e., *).
2. Type selectors (e.g., h1) and pseudo-elements (e.g., :before).
3. Class selectors (e.g., .example), attributes selectors (e.g., [type="radio"]) and pseudo-classes (e.g., :hover).
4. ID selectors (e.g., #example).

Inline style added to an element (e.g., style="font-weight:bold") always overwrites any styles in the CSS and thus can be though as having the biggest specificity.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The comments about inspecting actually worked - it was quite few classes.

Comment: May be it was your day today :)